# background texture issues (only on tablet, not on desktop/laptop pc)

Tags: css, background-image

I'm using a 1920x1080 high-resolution background texture image on my site. It looks great on a desktop or laptop PC.

As I scroll up/down the background texture remains fixed and consistent, looks great.
However on a tablet, the background is shown tiled every 25% section of the page (scrolling up/down).

I noticed this issue on both and iPad and Galaxy Tablet (all browsers).

Here is my code

```
  html, body {
    background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images//backgrounds/white-paper-texture-hd.jpg");
    background-attachment: scroll}
```

I'm looking for some insight on what could be causing this issue and what solutions I should try
 Thanks

Comment: You saying the background is fixed on your text. while on code you have it scroll. can you provide the fiddle.

Comment: What is "shown tiled"? Could you provide screen shots of the differences in display? Anyway, you have background images on both the HTML and the BODY? That doesn't seem right. What if you remove one of them? Also, this could be just me, but I don't like double slashes in file paths.

Comment: Update, the vertical up/down tile of the background is evident on not just a tablet but also a desktop. Apparently I don't have permission to post a pic or screenshot on my stackexchange account and I'd rather not publish the URL. I'll look into my options and get back. Mr. Lister, yes I will try your suggestion